# How to pass a function as argument

Tags: function, parameter-passing, scilab

I'm using Scilab and I'm trying to make a function like the following:

```
function p = binary_search(myf,a,b)
```

The target is to make a `binary_search` to find such p that: `myf(p) = 0` in [a,b].

I want to do something like this:

```
root = binary_search("x^3 - 10",1,2)
```

Where the first string is a definition of a function.

The only way I found is defining a function called `x3`:

```
function x = x3(p)
x = p^3 - 10;
endfunction
```

and then, inside `binary_search`, do something like:

```
fa = x3(a);
```

Any ideas?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
In the main window (the interpreter), I define the function like:

```
deff('[y] = square(x)','y=x^2')
```

Then, I call

```
 bi(square,0,2)
```

In the function, I just do 'f(x)':

```
function [x] = bi(f,a,b)
    fa = f(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have defined the function `f(x) = x^3 - 10` , either using  `deff('y=f(x)','y=x^3-10')` or the regular "`function ... endfunction`" syntax, then you can simply pass f as an argument: define

```
function r = binary_search(f,a,b)
  % do the binary search here and store the result in r
endfunction
```

Then you can call

```
--->  binary_search(f, 1, 2)
```

which works fine in SciLab.

In MATLAB/octave, the interpreter considers " `f` " as an equivalent for `f()`, i.e., it would execute the function f without arguments, which will result in an error "x undefined". To avoid this, you have to type an `@`  in front of f:

```
--->  binary_search( @f, 1, 2)   %% in MATLAB/octave
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions in Scilab can be passed as arguments to other functions. Therefore, if you have one function, f:

```
function y=f(x)  
  y = x^3 - 10     
endfunction
```

you are free to pass that to another function,

```
root = binary_search("x^3 - 10",1,2)
```

deff is simply a way to quickly define a function- usually inline on the interpreter.

Alternatively, you can also pass an expression as a string to a function and have that evaluated using the evstr command:

```
function p = binary_search(expression, a, b)
    evstr expression
    //Rest of your code
endfunction
```

You would implement this on the interpreter thus:

```
expression = "a^3 - 10"

root = binary_search(expression, 1, 2)
```